# C's getopt not able to parse options at the end (or in between) of argv

Tags: c, glibc, getopt, unistd.h

I love [getopt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) to parse options from the `argv` argument. Unfortunately I'm not able to make `getopt` parse options that are between nonoptions or at the end of `argv`. Example Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int o_help = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int opt, i;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "h")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 'h':
                o_help = 1;
                break;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

    printf("o_help=%d\n", o_help);
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s ", argv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Running the program in an alpine container on macOS Mojave, I get the following outputs:

```
$ gcc prog.c
$ ./a.out hello -h world
o_help=0
hello -h world
$ ./a.out -h hello world
o_help=1
-h hello world
```

The official `getopt` man page states:

> By default, getopt() permutes the contents of argv as it scans, so that eventually all the nonoptions are at the end.

Since I did not specify otherwise, I expect the default behaviour to 1. parse the `-h` option and 2. permute `argv` so that the nonoptions are at the end of the array. Unfortunately, calling the program like `./a.out hello -h world` does neither parse `-h` nor permute the array. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't reproduce (With Ubuntu). Do you perhaps have the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable set? With the glibc version of `getopt()`, that would give the results you're seeing.

Comment: (I'm assuming that *alpine container* refers to a Alpine Linux VM. If it's something else and you're using the OS X version of `getopt()` but looking at the glibc documentation...)

Comment: Actually, looks like Alpine uses musl, not glibc. So, yeah. Sure you're looking at the right documentation?

Comment: @Shawn I'm working on a docker [alpine linux container](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) which runs as a process on OS X. I installed standard library using `apk add libc-dev`, I'm not quite sure whether this is the `glibc` implementation. But you're probably right, for example the OS X man page on [getopt](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/getopt.3.html) doesn't provide such a behaviour: "When all options have been processed (i.e., up to the first non-option argument), getopt() returns -1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marco's answer is correct, but "install glibc by yourself" is really not a good suggestion if you're not using a glibc-based distribution; you'd be building a whole parallel library ecosystem by yourself. There are a couple canonical solutions to your problem that are much easier.

The GNU-endorsed method of using nonstandard GNU behaviors like the one you want is to use gnulib and autoconf, which can automatically replace getopt with a GNU version as needed. However that's a heavy change and it requires your program to be GPL'd.

A much easier solution is just using `getopt_long` with a degenerate list of long options, instead of `getopt`. Since `getopt_long` is not a standard-governed function but an extension originally define on GNU, musl's implementation of it is free to follow the GNU behavior of permuting `argv` to allow mixed options and non-option arguments, and does so.

Comment: Thank you very much, I never checked the documentation of `getopt_long` - it's awesome and does in fact also permute argv in the `musl` implementation, which I've just checked.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the manual page for the [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) version of `getopt()`. Alpine Linux does not use glibc, it uses [musl libc](https://musl.libc.org/).

Looking at differences between the two, from [this page](https://wiki.musl-libc.org/functional-differences-from-glibc.html) of the musl libc wiki you can read:

> GNU getopt permutes argv to pull options to the front, ahead of non-option arguments. **musl and the POSIX standard getopt stop processing options at the first non-option argument with no permutation**.

So, the solution here is:

1. Use musl, but permute `argv` by yourself before calling `getopt()`.
2. Install glibc [by yourself](https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc) or use an [already made Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-glibc/).

Comment: "Install glibc by yourself" is really not a good suggestion if you're not using a glibc-based distribution; you're going to be building a whole parallel library ecosystem by yourself. I'll post a better alternative.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE you're not going to build anything by yourself, it's already packaged and installable in a second.

Comment: OP is going to need to build whatever software they're writing/building, which likely depends on an ecosystem of libraries not just libc. Moreover Apline does not ship a glibc cross compiler for compiling against glibc, so they'd have to setup that too.